# Testing URLs in groovy

Tags: groovy, url

How can we check whether urls are working or not in groovy?
when we click a button, i will get all the urls from existing db from 'urls' table and need to check which url is working 
Ex:
http://baldwinfilter.com/products/start.html - not working 
http://www.subaru.com/ - working 
and so many urls from db.

My aim is to get all urls and check which one is working and which is not .
do we need to check on the status it returns ??
Can any one help me giving idea ...

thanks in advance
sri...

Answer (score 5):

You could use HttpBuilder like so:

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.5.0-RC2' )
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder

def urls = [
  "http://baldwinfilter.com/products/start.html",
  "http://www.subaru.com/" 
]

def up = urls.collect { url ->
  try {
    new HTTPBuilder( url ).get( path:'' ) { response ->
      response.statusLine.statusCode == 200
    }
  }
  catch( e ) { false }
}
println up
```

Comment: Hi tim yates,
I was getting erors with first line says "unexpected token:import @line 2, column 1. i tried removing first line and deployed but it shows "org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder".
Can you please tell me to include any jars ??

Comment: Sounds like the Grab issue in Groovy version 1.6.  Can you try with 1.7.1?  Looking up the download URLs as I type this, but the site's down :-(

Comment: Oh god, checked in ubuntu synaptic shows version groovy 1.5.7.1, 
I should update to latest version 1.7.1 ?

Comment: 1.5 is kinda old.  Incase you need it though, the http-builder can be downloaded form here: http://repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus/groovy/modules/http-builder/http-builder/

Comment: thanks tim, i will try with this, if not anyways will upgrade to 1.7.1  .so that Grab will come default with 1.7.1. I will be in touch with you .

Comment: Still i was getting same issue with 1.7.1 .
srinath@srinath-laptop:~$ groovy -v
Groovy Version: 1.7.1 JVM: 1.6.0_17
when added - @Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.5.0-RC2' )
netbeans giving "unexpected token:import @line 2, column 1"
Do i need to add any external jars ??
I just upgraded to 1.7.1 and added lines on top of file . nothing did next, immediately shows error warnings .
Please help me tim .

thanks in advance

Comment: How are you trying to run this? Does it work from the command line?

Comment: yes,this is working from command line , i created a file "test.groovy" and pasted your code and it works when run "groovy test". But not working from Netbeans, shows error message when include "@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.5.0-RC2' ) . Do we need to import or include any thing ?

Comment: What version of Groovy is NetBeans using?  I have NetBeans 6.8 and it seems to be set to use 1.6.4

Comment: Groovy 1.6.4.Netbeans 6.8. It showed under Tools -> Libraries.
hmmm but showing 
srinath@srinath-laptop:~$ groovy -v
Groovy Version: 1.7.1 JVM: 1.6.0_17 from terminal

Comment: Yeah, NetBeans uses groovy-all that is bundled with NetBeans.  Not sure if you can just change this to point to groovy-all in a more recent download of groovy or not (Not sure if it would break the grails integration -- it shouldn't do I guess as grails has it's own groovy-all inside grails/lib).  I am rapidly coming to the conclusion that NetBeans support for Groovy is falling behind, and it might be time to investigate IntelliJ idea (the free version does groovy, but you have to pay for the grails support)

Comment: So then it should work from outside Netbeans. right?. I will try to find a work around meanwhile.Thank you tim for giving valuable comments.

Comment: Yeah, it should work outside of netbeans so long as you either have a recent enough version of Groovy to use the @Grab annotation, or you download the http-builder and all of it's dependencies from the link in the 4th comment on this thread, and include them in your classpath :-)  Good luck!

Comment: Hi Tim, sorry to interrupt you again, downloaded latest groovy-all-1.7.1.jar and added in tools -> libraries -> Groovy-1.6.4 and removed previous jar groovy-all.jar, but still the issue persists . I'm unable to understand why this is working from command line for .groovy file and not working for IDE, also tried creating app from outside but no luck. Could you please give me suggestion for working under Netbeans , I'm running behind schedule these days with this .I can send you screenshots what i did. Thanks in advance

Comment: As I said, I don't know if netbeans supports Groovy 1.7.  Have you tried the free version of IntelliJ IDEA?  That supports it

Comment: Or, as I also said, you could try downloading the JARs for Http-Builder and just add them to your classpath (and get rid of the Grab line)

Comment: I installed IntelliJ commercial 30 days trial package and the same issue repeats here too . I have grails-1.1.2/lib/groovy-all-1.6.3.jar . Is it the problem with this ??