# check rss feed is down using groovy Xmlparser

Tags: grails, groovy, rss, feed

I wants to put condition to check rss feed is down or up.

SAMPLE CODE

```
def url= 'http://'+
'www.groovyblogs.org/feed/rss'
def rss = new XmlParser().parse(url)
rss.channel.item.title[0..9]*.text()
```

How do i check whether www.groovyblogs.org/feed/rss is up or down.
I want to handle something when feed is down.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to handle something when feed is down.

You can wrap the above code block in `try` and do the error handling in `catch`.

If you want to check beforehand that if url is working or not [Testing URLs in groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442749/testing-urls-in-groovy) should help.